# Change in glibc not working

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86

I have downloaded *glibc* so that I can modify its code and then use it. So just for the sake of playing with it, I changed the *printf* function in the directory *stdio-common* of *glibc*, so that it prints "Can you see me?".

```
int
__printf (const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list arg;
  int done;

  va_start (arg, format);
  done = vfprintf (stdout, "Can you see me?", arg);
  va_end (arg);

  return done;
}
```

After making that change I compiled the *glibc* and then used the LD_PRELOAD with the *libc.so* in this *glibc* directory to run a sample program using *printf*. However, I still see *printf* printing normally, that is, the change made by me is not reflected. What mistake am I doing here?

Comment: Change that duplicate line to simply print "hello" or something.  You are processing the va_list twice, and that doesn't work - the first call depletes it.

Comment: I made some other change previously which was to print character+1 instead of character, that didn't work too!

Comment: What does `ldd ./test-program` say?  Also, doing `export LD_DEBUG=files` before running your program may give you useful information.

Comment: But LD_PRELOAD is prescribed when running the file, that is to override the so file used by the program, right? So how does ldd help here? Seems like LD_PRELOAD is not working here?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: I don't know about how `LD_PRELOAD` might affect `ldd` - I have never used `LD_PRELOAD`.

Answer (score 1):

There may be several reasons for that, the simplest is that you used a string with no real format, and the compiler changed the call from `printf` to `puts`:

```
printf("hello\n");
// becomes:
puts("hello");
```

Try adding a parameter:

```
char ex = '!';
printf("Hello %c\n", ex);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, checked the code with objdump and it is indeed using printf, not puts!

Comment: IIRC printf("%s", "hello\n") also gets converted internally to puts("hello\n"). This is a bit of a gotcha as glibc printf() is quite kind and will check for NULL and print out something appropriate whereas puts() doesn't and will segfault.